# Tensorflow Experimental Dataset: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 30: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, machine-translation

My dataset is a set of 2 columns with Spanish and English sentences. I created a training dataset using the Dataset API using the below code:

```
train_examples =  tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset("./Data/train.csv", [tf.string, tf.string])
val_examples = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset("./Data/validation.csv", [tf.string, tf.string])
```

##Create a custom subwords tokenizer from the training dataset.

```
tokenizer_en = tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus(
    (en.numpy() for pt, en in train_examples), target_vocab_size=2**13)

tokenizer_pt = tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus(
    (pt.numpy() for pt, en in train_examples), target_vocab_size=2**13)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 30: invalid continuation byte
```

Traceback:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-c90f5c60daf2> in <module>
      1 tokenizer_en = tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus(
----> 2     (en.numpy() for pt, en in train_examples), target_vocab_size=2**13)
      3 
      4 tokenizer_pt = tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus(
      5     (pt.numpy() for pt, en in train_examples), target_vocab_size=2**13)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/features/text/subword_text_encoder.py in build_from_corpus(cls, corpus_generator, target_vocab_size, max_subword_length, max_corpus_chars, reserved_tokens)
    291         generator=corpus_generator,
    292         max_chars=max_corpus_chars,
--> 293         reserved_tokens=reserved_tokens)
    294 
    295     # Binary search on the minimum token count to build a vocabulary with

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/features/text/subword_text_encoder.py in _token_counts_from_generator(generator, max_chars, reserved_tokens)
    394   token_counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
    395   for s in generator:
--> 396     s = tf.compat.as_text(s)
    397     if max_chars and (num_chars + len(s)) >= max_chars:
    398       s = s[:(max_chars - num_chars)]

~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py in as_text(bytes_or_text, encoding)
     85     return bytes_or_text
     86   elif isinstance(bytes_or_text, bytes):
---> 87     return bytes_or_text.decode(encoding)
     88   else:
     89     raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' % bytes_or_text)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 30: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Simply saving the CSV to 'CSV UTF-8(Comma delimited)' format solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be due to the **name of your computer.** The name of your computer for the solution should not contain special characters. Change the name of your computer to only 26 latin characters.
[Changing computer name image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74TcW.png)

Comment: I think this inferior to explicitly specifying the encoding.